# Rails timezone does not work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This does not return time in the pacific timezone:

```
Time.use_zone "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" do
  Time.now
end
```

This works and returns time in pacific timezone:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

I am using gem Rails v4.1.0.rc1

Comment: I can confirm that it works in Rails 4.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work

```
Time.use_zone "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" do
  p Time.zone.now
end
```

Why? `Time.now` is not working

The answer is simple `Time.now` is Ruby's method and `Time.zone.now` is Rails method.

`Time.now` will give you the server time. But `Time.zone.now` will give you rails application time (which is set in config.time_zone). When you do `Time.use_zone` giving block and timezone as parameter it will use this timezone as default in the block. But calling `Time.now` still fetches the time of the operating system which is not changed.

From [#use_zone **Rails** API](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/use_zone/class) and [#now **Ruby** API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-c-now)